# How to create chatbox and notification system using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I'm working on a SocialNetwork WebApplication and I don't know how to create a working chatbox and notification system like Facebook, I searched the web alot and I couldn't find anything helpful to start with, the problem is I don't know a good way to send feedback immediately to user when there is change in database.

EDIT: I don't want to do it using ajax, if there is anyway someone can give me an example using socketprogramming ?

Answer (score 3):

SignalR is currently the best choice for real-time communication between the browser and server when developing with ASP.net.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: The first link (the github link) has clear Nuget installation instructions if you scroll down to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is heavy use of AJAX both for notifications and chat messages.(Unless you are going to use `websockets` which is a newer technology.)

The simplest way to update changes in database to chat app is by making a small JavaScript code **poll** the server for changes after each time interval, like a second.

Comment: I can do it using ajax but it's not a good way I need a faster way to do it

Comment: you can't skip ajax..its only way .. answer given by every one uses AJAX at its core.. the only other thing is WebSockets

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not an answer, just some suggestions;

==Ajax==

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajax-chat/

==Silverlight==

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34198/Build-a-Silverlight-Web-Chatroom-with-Multiple-Roo

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33346/Build-a-Silverlight-2-Web-Chat-Application

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-Web-Chat-With-WCF-Callbacks.aspx

==Ready to use==

http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-free-website-chat-widgets-to-make-your-site-interactive/